# How to run forever for production build

Tags: reactjs, npm, forever

I am trying to run production build of react application.

forever start -c "serve -s build" build/

I am not able to run the production build using forever.
Can one help how to run the production build in forever.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.